# Determining the COM Port of a (USB enabled) Customer Display

Tags: c#, winforms

I have connected customer Display with POS application. I am using serial port class for display message on customer Display. To message I need to know with com port this USB display are using. I have searched allowed there are many examples for getting all com pot for that computer but I am able to find any help to get particular com port no e.g COM93,COM01 or COM2.

I have tried following program and also I have tried Microsoft program WMI code creator.

```
// Get a list of serial port names.
string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

Console.WriteLine("The following serial ports were found:");

// Display each port name to the console.
foreach (string port in ports)
{
    Console.WriteLine(port);
}

Console.ReadLine();

SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
sp.PortName = "COM93";------------- How i can find this no automatic 
sp.BaudRate = 9600;
sp.Parity = Parity.None;
sp.DataBits = 8;
sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
sp.Open();
sp.Write("\f");
sp.WriteLine("***Velkommen***");
sp.Close();
sp.Dispose();
sp = null;
```

I have tried following solution as well, to use this as well for this I get access denied so I need to edit registory to give rights that I dot wana do I want solution programmatically

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI", "SELECT * FROM MSSerial_PortName");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public string Get_RegistryInfo(string VID, string PID)
        {
            try
            {
                RegistryKey rk1 = Registry.LocalMachine;
                // HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
                RegistryKey rk2 = rk1.OpenSubKey("HARDWARE\\\\DEVICEMAP\\\\SERIALCOMM");
                // HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\\\\DEVICEMAP\\\\SERIALCOMM
                VendorID = VID;
                ProduktID = PID;
                string pattern = string.Format("^VID_{0}.PID_{1}", VID, PID);
                Regex _rx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                string rk2_SubKeyNames = null;
                foreach (string rk2_SubKeyNames_loopVariable in rk2.GetValueNames())
                {
                    rk2_SubKeyNames = rk2_SubKeyNames_loopVariable;
                    if (rk2_SubKeyNames == "\\Device\\ProlificSerial0")
                    {
                        COM_Port = rk2.GetValue(rk2_SubKeyNames).ToString();                        
                    }
                }
                return COM_Port;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return COM_Port;
            }

        }
```